# Retrofit 2 convert Object to Json on request

Tags: java, jax-rs, retrofit, retrofit2

I have class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "myobject")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MyObject {

    @XmlElement
    private Long id;
    @XmlElement
    private String name;
    ...
}
```

I use Retrofit 2 to send data to the server. Req

Method into interface:

```
@POST("/update")
Call<Response> updateObject(@Body MyObject myObject);
```

When i use this:

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(API_URL)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();
ServerAPI api = getRetrofit().create(ServerAPI.class);
Call<Response> call = api.updateObject(myObject);
...
retrofit2.Response response = call.execute();
...
```

sent to the server

```
{"id":3,"name"}
```

but i need

```
{myobject:{"id":3,"name"}}
```

i.e. wrap body in {myobject}. How to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest thing to do would be to wrap your response around the object you're trying to send.

```
public class ObjectWrapper {
  @SerializedName("myobject")
  public final MyObject myObject;

  public ObjectWrapper(MyObject myObject) {
    this.myObject = myObject;
  }
}
```